# DataGridViewCell event sequence

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I apologize if I duplicate another question but I couldn't find relevant answer.

 I have databound columns in `DataGridView`. Columns in question are bound to `decimal` fields of data objects and need to be committed to `database` as `decimal` However, I need convert certain `string` values to `decimal` when user enters the `string`. Example: when user enters M12, as soon as he/she leaves the cell, it needs to be converted to `decimal` value 0.4724. I have a method that takes the `string` and returns correct `decimal` but I can't find correct `event` to handle. All events I choose as too late and I end up getting exceptions before I get to convert `string` to `decimal`. What event should I handle? `

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style
        .SelectionBackColor = Color.Empty;
}
```